# VC Dimension Calculation for Intervals

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, pattern-recognition, vc-dimension

As i See in ML Course a VC dimension calculation is very theoretical.

What is the VC-dimension of intervals in R?

The target function is specifieed by an interval, and labels any example positive i it lies inside that interval.

Answers:

VC-dim = 2. A set of two points can be shattered, since there's only a single block of positive examples that could lie within the interval. But no set of 3 points can be shattered, because it can not be labeled in alternating +; - ; + order.

so i'm get stuck with meaning of interval.

for example, it means {(a, b) | "a is lower than b", a,b is real number} has VC-dim = 2?

Any idea or solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The definition of intervals is on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as $(a,b) = ]a,b[ = \left \{ x \in \mathbb{R}|\,a<x<b\right \} $. It has two parameters $a$ and $b$. The sets of all open intervals, i.e. $\left \{  \left \{ x \in \mathbb{R}|\,a<x<b\right \} | a,b \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ has a VC dimension of 2 for the reason you mention. Keep in mind that the VC dimension of a hypothesis set $H$ is **the most points** $H$ can shatter.). To put it graphically:

[image]

(image from CalTech's free machine Learning online course by Yaser Abu-Mostafa [Learning from Data](http://work.caltech.edu/lectures.html))

Comment: i confused !! yes or no :) Dear Richerby, be aware that a is lower than b, not lower equal than b !

Comment: Thanks, I clarified the answer. Let me know If it's okay now. The strict inequality works too as you can take b arbitrarily close to a anyway.

Comment: Dear Franck, some bracket insert wrongly in your anwers. can you put some detail to your answers?

Comment: @Ebraham Thanks for the feedback, which bracket insert is wrong and where are you stuck?

Comment: no you correct it. just i want to find different between [-infinity <x <a, x is real number] with this example. i think this is a threshold and has a VC= 1. it's not interval ? yes?

Comment: [-infinity <x <a, x is real number] is a ray. A ray is an interval with an infinite endpoint. The set of rays has a VC dimension of 1. All rays are intervals, but the reciprocal is false.